# Python: Filter list full of unicode and lists to just strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, lambda

Say I have a list of lists like the following.

```
lst = [[u'1'], [[], [u'Qjfe dw Dvrferk (bfw)'], []], [u'86,865,281'], [u'$22.34'], [u'-0.31'], [u'-1.37']]
```

What would be the best approach (preferably using lambda) to turn it into a list of strings like this.

```
lst = ['1', 'Qjfe dw Dvrferk (bfw)', '86,865,281', '$22.34', '-0.31', '-1.37']
```

Comment: On second thought, I can work with a list of unicode instead of strings if its easier.

Comment: can you have more than 1 item per sub-list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a deep flatten to me.

```
def deep_flatten(L):
    for e in L:
        if isinstance(e, list):
           for e in deep_flatten(e):
               yield e
        else:
            yield e

lst = [[u'1'], [[], [u'Qjfe dw Dvrferk (bfw)'], []], [u'86,865,281'], [u'$22.34'], [u'-0.31'], [u'-1.37']]

list(deep_flatten(lst))
```

results in:

```
[u'1', u'Qjfe dw Dvrferk (bfw)', u'86,865,281', u'$22.34', u'-0.31', u'-1.37']
```